# How to start external application from Scala

Tags: scala

How to start external application from Scala?

Answer (score 9):

Use the [Process](http://github.com/harrah/process) library, which was a part of SBT but is now being separated from it. You can find it [here](http://www.scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scala-tools/sbt/process/) in the Scala Tools repository.

With that, it can be as simple as:

```
import Process._
"find project -name *.jar" ! log
```

**Edit**

As for Scala 2.9.0, this is available on the standard library, under `scala.sys.process`. Instead of importing `Process._`, you should import `scala.sys.process._`, the package object.

Comment: Just what I was hoping for. But last the first last and only release was «November 19, 2009».

Comment: @Martin It evolved inside SBT, and has recently been added to Scala's standard library, under `scala.sys`. It is likely that it will be available starting with Scala 2.9.0.

Comment: The process DSL is cool but difficult to remember : need to import the implicits and then just put the command line in a string - but with the all-important bang '!' to coerce the implicit.

Comment: @javadba Well, use the `Process` constructor, then, and use IDE's type completion.

Answer (score 2):

Since Scala runs on the JVM, you can do this the same way as you would in Java, by using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` (look that up in the [Java API documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/)).

You can also use `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` for more control.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("external_program")`

Answer (score 1):

This will open file with default program :

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop.open(new java.io.File("<PATH_TO_FILE>"))
```

Doc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)

Comment: maybe not the *likely* answer but it is interesting: just opened a pdf file in Preview that way!

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good library (DSL) written for this called [simple-build-tool](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Process)

```
cat(file)  #| "grep -i scala" !
```